# Shouldn't assigning to a prototype property override it on the prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was trying to explain the rare use cases for prototypal inheritance to a coworker when I got stumped by the fact that this doesn't work like I expect.

```js
const baseobj = { baseproperty: 'original'};

const x = Object.create(baseobj);

//should add properties to x, not the base
x.newproperty = 'bar';
console.assert(x.newproperty != baseobj.newproperty);
//so far so good

//should modify the base, not x
x.baseproperty = 'foo';
console.assert(x.baseproperty == baseobj.baseproperty);
//this assert failed, property is on x!?
```

I'm confused. So far as I understand assignment is a two-step process, one to look up the property and another to assign to it. So why on earth is lookup of `baseproperty` not returning (and therefore modifying) `baseobj.baseproperty`?

I know *something* like this is key to how angularjs scopes work, but what specifically is going on here eludes me.

Comment: It would be bad if it did work that way. It would imply that assigning to a property could implicitly change other objects that happen to have the same prototype. Simplest example: `({}).toString = 42;`. Should *every* object's `toString` property now be `42`?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you're thinking about in Angular, but if you'd post some sort of example it would be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to a property on an object instance *always* creates an "own" property on the target object (if one doesn't exist of course). Prototype properties are never affected by such assignments, even if a prototype chain property matching the name does exist.

After the assignment, of course, the "own" property on the object hides the prototype chain property.

Comment: Even ones that exist on prototypes?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer yes, even ones that exist on prototypes. To put it another way, the only way to modify a prototype chain property is to find it directly on the appropriate prototype object and change it there.

Comment: Do you mind providing a reference? I'm pretty sure I read that the two-step process is core before (though obviously I have evidence to the contrary)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer it seems strange, but if you think about it there would be lots and lots of very bizarre bugs if it didn't work that way.

Comment: But isn't this exactly what angular scopes do that allow you to override the parent scope? I seem to remember even looking at the library code around this...

Comment: Sorry, it just doesn't work that way, as you can prove to yourself by trying it a few dozen times :) It's all in the semantics of "left-hand-side expression" and how that interacts with assignment operators.

Comment: A "left-hand-side" expression is always a reference to a property on the target object; no prototype chain lookup is performed. It's a different case in the language spec than a value (right-hand side) expression.

Comment: Explanation is on the mozilla site... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @GeorgeMauer There is a two-step process, the assignment *does* check whether there is an inherited property with that name. Because in the case of a setter property, that setter would be invoked. But if there is no setter anywhere, the property value is set directly at the target, not its prototype.